# APNS Send notification to all user's devices

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to get something unique about a user that will be found on all his devices?

I take that a device-token is unique per device itself, not user?

So is it possible to uniquely identify a user to record all his device-tokens on my server under him? Or is the only way to have the user sign in?

*I would like the setup to be automatic and have the user just open the app without having to sign-up/in.*

This is for APNS. I would like to send notifications to all the devices of a certain user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store all users tokens on server and have the user sign in at least *1 time* from each device, then You store each devices token for that user and log the user in automatically on subsequent app runs.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've got at the moment.

Comment: can it be any other way, has anyone invented any other way :)

You only need to login 1 time, that may not be too hard on the customer...